# How to use transform data in a new panel in Grafana with elasticsearch datasource?

Tags: elasticsearch, grafana

I have used transform "convert field type" in Grafana in order to convert one of my terms from string to time. Now I want to use the result in a query for filter on an time range. Do something like this : *what:some_name AND meta.date_keyword: ["now" TO "now+1y"]*

I have seen a lot of solution in SQL but unfortunaly I have an elasticsearch data source. I also have tried to change my metric but I have other dashboards who use the same metric.

Comment: One possible solution is to create a datalink to a dashoard using the result as a variable. I am not sure you can tell Grafana to reuse the result of a transform as a variable.